# check if id exists in multiple tables

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I am using SQL Server 2012.

I have 5 tables (lets call them A, B, C, D & E). Each table contains a column called m_id, which contains id's that are nvarchar(10).

I currently run the query below 5 times (changing the table name). To see if the table contains the id.

```
select m_id from A where m_id = 'some_id'
```

Basically I want to know if the id is any of the 5 tables, if so return 1 else if does not exist in any of the 5 tables return 0.

I feel the current way I'm doing this is very inefficient. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Check this answer - seems almost similar to what you are trying to do - http://stackoverflow.com/a/3281916

Comment: You could do a single query of a UNION ALL of all 5 tables.

Comment: How else can you look in 5 different tables for a given value without running 5 queries?

Comment: if you have an m_ table with all the m_ids, you can left outer join the 5 related tables

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use `UNION`(removes duplicates beforehand) or `UNION ALL`:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN EXISTS 
  ( SELECT 1 FROM ( SELECT m_id FROM  A 
                    UNION 
                    SELECT m_id FROM  B 
                    UNION 
                    SELECT m_id FROM  C 
                    UNION 
                    SELECT m_id FROM  D 
                    UNION 
                    SELECT m_id FROM  E ) All 
    WHERE  All.m_id = 'some_id') 
THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS ContainsID
```

Comment: Is this actually faster or more efficient? If it is could you explain why?

Comment: @Curmudgeon: faster than what? This is at least a single query. With proper indexes on `m_id` it should be efficient. But i don't understand why OP needs 5 tables at all. Normally one table should be  enough with another column `TypeID`.

Comment: @TimSchmelter: I mean faster than the 5 separate queries he's using now. I'm just curious, what's the advantage of a single, longer query over 5 shorter, faster ones? Indexes on `m_id` would improve performance in both cases.

Comment: @Curmudgeon: of course 5 queries are  slower than one query, the database can optimize it much better. Also, if you can't use multiple queries it's the only option.

Comment: I get an error on "All"? Doesn't this work for MSSQL?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN COUNT(*) > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as returnCode
FROM (
    SELECT m_id, N'A' as tableName FROM A WHERE m_id = 'some_id'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT m_id, N'B' as tableName FROM B WHERE m_id = 'some_id'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT m_id, N'C' as tableName FROM C WHERE m_id = 'some_id'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT m_id, N'D' as tableName FROM D WHERE m_id = 'some_id'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT m_id, N'E' as tableName FROM E WHERE m_id = 'some_id'
) data
```