# How can Reference Foreign key to Multiple tables?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, foreign-keys, constraints

I am trying to create a `BOM` structure i have 6 product tables which contains different attributes and a `BOMHEADER` and `BOMDETAIL` tables. Before creating the BOM structure i like to Validate or check the existence of the `bomitem` in either of the six tables. So i tried to creating `BOMHEADER` field as shown below using multiple constraints, but i get the following error message
["The INSERT Statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint](https://i.stack.imgur.com/unVLE.png)

What is the best way to resolve the issue.

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[BOMHEAD](
    [bomItem] [int] NOT NULL,
    [bomRev] [nvarchar](6) NOT NULL,
    [rollup] [bit] NULL,

 CONSTRAINT [PK_BOMHEAD_KEY_0] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [bomItem] ASC,
    [bomRev] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]

GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[BOMHEAD]  WITH CHECK ADD FOREIGN KEY([bomItem])
REFERENCES [dbo].[parts] ([itemId])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[BOMHEAD]  WITH CHECK ADD FOREIGN KEY([bomItem])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Tires] ([titemId])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[BOMHEAD]  WITH CHECK ADD FOREIGN KEY([bomItem])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Discs] ([itemId])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[BOMHEAD]  WITH CHECK ADD FOREIGN KEY([bomItem])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Rims] ([itemId])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[BOMHEAD]  WITH CHECK ADD FOREIGN KEY([bomItem])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Wheel] ([wheelItemId])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[BOMHEAD]  WITH CHECK ADD FOREIGN KEY([bomItem])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Assemblies] ([itemId])
GO
```

Comment: I think your issue might be that it's not checking for the existence of the foreign key in ANY of the tables, it's checking that it exists in ALL of the tables.

Comment: @RichBenner I tired with `NOCHECK AND CHECK ` I get the Same

Comment: I don't think foreign keys are what you're after, see if this helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30918873/check-if-id-exists-in-multiple-tables you may need a trigger to do what you're after.

Comment: @RichBenner you mean select CASE inside the Constraint? Thank you

Comment: Yeah, you could put it into one check constraint, that would be a neat answer

Answer (score 1):

The structure you post is not check that `bomItem` is exists in any of that given table but it is required that `bomItem` must exists in ALL TABLES.

You should do it the other way round by making BOMHEAD to primary key table and set fk of other table to refer pk on BOMHEAD.

This way it will guarantee that every other part table will have BOMHEAD.

The way you did is to guarantee that BOMHEAD will have every other parts.

But if you insist that `bomItem` need to check for existence in either of the six tables(maybe to prevent unwanted reference from other table?),You can't use fk what you need is check constrain with user defined function or create association table which maintain the relation between BOMHEAD and others.

Answer (score 0):

You should have general table with BOMs that are referenced via Foreign Key by all these tables.

Comment: you mean just for the BOM structure or Master product table?  For the BOM structure I have `BOMDETAIL`   table  store parent and childs but my problem the HEADER table Assembled Item ID need to be check. to create Master Product table each table have more than 15 different attributes. Thank you