# Check if string exists in two tables

Tags: sql-server

If the a given string(the ID) exists in two tables, I want to return the ID. How can this easily be acheived? I tried with a join, but it wasn't relaibale

```
  SELECT t1.ACCOUNTNUM FROM table1 T1
         JOIN table2 T2 ON T1.ACCOUNTNUM = T2.ITEMID     
    where t1.accountnum = '123'
```

I also tried the answer posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30919026/2715404), but the syntax All did not work in newest version of mssql.

Comment: Can you share your tables structures, data input and expected output?

Comment: What do you mean with " the syntax All did not work in newest version of mssql." In your linked answer "All" is just an alias, change it to something else (probably is a keyword)

Comment: *"I tried with a left join, but it wasn't relaibale"* Why wasn't it? I would have, however, thought an `INNER JOIN` would be the option you're after, based on your description

Comment: Sorry for the  unclear description @honeybadger. I think the reason is that the column is not named the same in the tables, and thus I have to specify the column name in each select. Therefor the All syntax is not valid.

Comment: @larnu the query doesn't return a row, even though the ID exist in both tables. Tested with inner also.

Comment: If the ID doesn't exist in both tablse, and the `INNER JOIN` returned a row, then your `ON` clause was wrong. If the `INNER JOIN` didn't, then the ID isn't in the other table (or your `ON` clause was wrong again).

Comment: Sample data is best served as [DDL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_definition_language) + [DML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_manipulation_language). Please [edit] your question to include it, your current attempt and your desired results.

Answer (score 1):

If the relation is one-to-one then a simple `INNER JOIN` would work:

```
SELECT T1.ID
FROM dbo.Table1 T1
     JOIN dbo.Table2 T2 ON T1.ID = T2.ID;
```

Alternatively, or if it is a one-to-many relationship, you can use `EXISTS`

```
SELECT T1.ID
FROM dbo.Table1 t1 --Assumed this is the singleton table
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM dbo.Table2 T2 --Assumed this is the many table
              WHERE T2.ID = T1.ID);
```

Comment: But there should be a specified ID. It should basically check if a specific ID exist in both tables. Your suggested answer returns all ids.

Comment: Then why didn't you state that in yoru qusetion, @miniHessel ? And if that is the case, add a clause to the `WHERE` for `T1.ID = {Some Value}`.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose, two tables are A and B. Both have ID column which is of type nvarchar(10). Then you can try a INNER JOIN to find out if both of the table has the same ID.

```
 SELECT A.ID FROM 
 A INNER JOIN B 
 ON A.ID =  B.ID
 WHERE A.ID = '123'
```

If you have multiple table(more than two) and want to check if any of those table has a specific ID, then you should try a UNION operation on those tables. Then check if the Result of UNION has that specific ID.

```
SELECT RESULT.ID ( SELECT ID FROM  A 
                UNION 
                SELECT ID FROM  B 
                UNION 
                SELECT ID FROM  C 
                UNION 
                SELECT ID FROM  D 
                UNION 
                SELECT ID FROM  E ) RESULT 
WHERE  RESULT.ID = '123'
```